# Adding productFlavor specific new activity via Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity, android-productflavors

I have a project with two flavors : `FlavorA` and `FlavorB`.

When trying to add a new activity I see no option of adding it only for a sprcific product flavor. It always adds it to the main sourceSet. I need to then manually move it to the source folder for the product flavor.

So the question, can i pick a product flavor to add a new activity to and not add it to main sourceset?

Also, can the directory structure for the flavors be auto generated when a new flavor is added?

Answer (score 1):

You can always select a folder in Project structure -> Right click -> New -> Activity. Select a folder of your flavor.
Probably you will have to have [separate manifests](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/manifest-merger) for each flavor.

Comment: yes figured that should work. Have you ever tried auto-generated the folder structure for a newly added product flavor?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I have created it by myself, because usually didn't need much difference between flavors..